# JApplet in JNLP file returns error

Tags: java, applet, jnlp

I have a Java Applet that works so far. Now I would like to start this applet via Web Start.

I have the files

```
  Multithreading.class
  test1.class
  test2.class
  manifest.txt
  index.html
  WebStart.jnlp
```

I build the `jar` file with `jar cvfm WebStart.jar manifest.txt *.class`

The html file contains:

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Web start</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  </head>
  <body>
    <applet
    alt = "Web start"
    code = 'Multithreading'
    jnlp_href = 'WebStart.jnlp',
    width = 500,
    height = 500 />
  </body>
</html>
```

and the JNLP file:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    <information>
    <title>Web start</title>
    <vendor>Self</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
    <j2se version="1.8+"
         href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="WebStart.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <applet-desc 
     name="Web start"
     main-class="Multithreading"
     width="500"
     height="500">
     </applet-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

The java versions I use are `java -XshowSettings:properties -version`:

```
 Property settings:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    file.encoding = UTF-8
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = /
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.print.PSPrinterJob
    java.class.path = .
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext
    /usr/java/packages/lib/ext
    java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
    java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
    java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    /usr/lib/jni
    /lib
    /usr/lib
    java.runtime.name = OpenJDK Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_45-internal-b14
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_45-internal
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.45-b02
    line.separator = \n 
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Linux
    os.version = 3.19.0-26-generic
    path.separator = :
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jfr.jar
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/classes
```

So now when I put the `html`, `jnlp` and the `jar` file in my `/var/www/html` directory and call it with `localhost/index.html` I get the following error:

```
    Error: Unable to fetch applet instance id from Java side.
    Error on Java side:
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    java.lang.NullPointerException     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.NetxPanel.ourRunLoader(NetxPanel.java:117)     at sun.applet.AppletViewerPanelAccess.run(AppletViewerPanelAccess.java:86)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:901) 
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.getApplet(Launcher.java:668) 
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:728) 
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1471) 
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClassExt(JNLPClassLoader.java:1670) 
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1653) 
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$CodeBaseClassLoader.findClassNonRecursive(JNLPClassLoader.java:2473) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$CodeBaseClassLoader$1.run(JNLPClassLoader.java:2474) 
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$CodeBaseClassLoader$1.run(JNLPClassLoader.java:2476) 
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$CodeBaseClassLoader.access$2001(JNLPClassLoader.java:2445) 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449) 
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Multithreading : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 
        at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:927) 
    Exception in thread "Applet" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Multithreading : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Multithreading : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$CodeBaseClassLoader.access$2001(JNLPClassLoader.java:2445)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$CodeBaseClassLoader$1.run(JNLPClassLoader.java:2476)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$CodeBaseClassLoader$1.run(JNLPClassLoader.java:2474)     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$CodeBaseClassLoader.findClassNonRecursive(JNLPClassLoader.java:2473)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1653)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClassExt(JNLPClassLoader.java:1670)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1471)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:728)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.getApplet(Launcher.java:668)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:901) 
    Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
    Selecting proxy for: socket://localhost:80
    Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
    Selecting proxy for: http://localhost/Multithreading.class
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    System logger called with result of 0
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Multithreading : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.access$1701(JNLPClassLoader.java:103)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$5.run(JNLPClassLoader.java:1636)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$5.run(JNLPClassLoader.java:1634)     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1633)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClassExt(JNLPClassLoader.java:1670)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1471)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:728)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.getApplet(Launcher.java:668)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:901) 
    Class-Path attribute cleared for /home/dan/.cache/icedtea-web/cache/21/http/localhost/WebStart.jar
    Stored action for unsigned applet at http://localhost/ was A - Always trust this (matching) applet(s)
    Codebase matches codebase manifest attribute, but application is unsigned. Continuing. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/no_redeploy.html for details.
    Trusted Only manifest attribute not found. Continuing.
    Permission added: ("java.io.FilePermission" "/home/dan/.cache/icedtea-web/cache/21/http/localhost/WebStart.jar" "read")
    Activate native: http://localhost/WebStart.jar
    Activate jar: file:/home/dan/.cache/icedtea-web/cache/21/http/localhost/WebStart.jar
    Jars not ready to provide main class
    Jars not ready to provide attribute Application-Name
    Jar found at /home/dan/.cache/icedtea-web/cache/21/http/localhost/WebStart.jarhas been verified as UNSIGNED
    App already has trusted publisher: false
    Jar found at /home/dan/.cache/icedtea-web/cache/21/http/localhost/WebStart.jarhas been verified as UNSIGNED
    @ /WebStart.jar
    -(DOWNLOAD)
    +(DOWNLOADED)
    Status: CONNECTED DOWNLOADED STARTED
    @ /WebStart.jar
    -(CONNECTING)
    +(CONNECTED)
    Status: CONNECTED DOWNLOAD STARTED
    isCurrent: http://localhost/WebStart.jar = true
    Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
    Selecting proxy for: http://localhost/WebStart.jar
    best url for location=http://localhost/WebStart.jar state=CONNECTING DOWNLOAD STARTED is http://localhost/WebStart.jar by HEAD
    Key : Server ,Value : [Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)]
    Key : Accept-Ranges ,Value : [bytes]
    Key : Connection ,Value : [Keep-Alive]
    Key : Content-Type ,Value : [application/java-archive]
    Key : Keep-Alive ,Value : [timeout=5, max=99]
    Key : Last-Modified ,Value : [Wed, 02 Sep 2015 12:18:18 GMT]
    Key : Content-Length ,Value : [4239]
    Key : Date ,Value : [Wed, 02 Sep 2015 13:13:31 GMT]
    Key : ETag ,Value : ["108f-51ec2a96a42f7"]
    Key : null ,Value : [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
    Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
    Selecting proxy for: http://localhost/WebStart.jar
    All possible urls for location=http://localhost/WebStart.jar state=CONNECTING DOWNLOAD STARTED : [http://localhost/WebStart.jar, http://localhost/WebStart.jar]
    @ /WebStart.jar
    -(CONNECT)
    +(CONNECTING)
    Status: CONNECTING DOWNLOAD STARTED
    @ /WebStart.jar
    +(DOWNLOAD)
    Status: CONNECT DOWNLOAD STARTED
    @ /WebStart.jar
    +(CONNECT)
    Status: CONNECT STARTED
    @ /WebStart.jar
    +(STARTED)
    Jars not ready to provide main class
    Status: STARTED
    Jars not ready to provide attribute Application-Name
    New classloader: http://localhost/WebStart.jnlp
            result: null
    Jars not ready to provide main class
    Jars not ready to provide attribute Application-Name
    Acquired shared lock on /tmp/dan/netx/locks/netx_running to indicate javaws is running
    Jars not ready to provide main class
    Jars not ready to provide attribute Application-Name
    UNIQUEKEY=1441199611454-1695405956-http://localhost/WebStart.jnlp
    Acceptable vendor tag found, contains: Self
    Acceptable title tag found, contains: Web start
    Jars not ready to provide attribute Application-Name
    Description: null
    Homepage: null
    line: 24

    line: 23
    line: 22
    line: 21
    line: 20
    line: 19
    line: 18 </jnlp>
    line: 17      <update check="background"/>
    line: 16      </applet-desc>
    line: 15      height="500">
    line: 14      width="500"
    line: 13      main-class="Multithreading"
    line: 12      name="Web start"
    line: 11    <applet-desc
    line: 10    </resources>
    line: 9     <jar href="WebStart.jar" main="true" />
    line: 8         href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    line: 7     <j2se version="1.8+"
    line: 6    <resources>
    line: 5    </information>
    line: 4      <vendor>Self</vendor>
    line: 3     <title>Web start</title>
    line: 2    <information>
    <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    @ /WebStart.jnlp
    -(DOWNLOADING)
    +(DOWNLOADED)
    Status: CONNECTED DOWNLOADED STARTED
    Downloadinghttp://localhost/WebStart.jnlp using http://localhost/WebStart.jnlp (encoding : null)
    Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
    Selecting proxy for: socket://localhost:80
    Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
    Selecting proxy for: http://localhost/WebStart.jnlp
    @ /WebStart.jnlp
    -(DOWNLOAD)
    +(DOWNLOADING)
    Status: CONNECTED DOWNLOADING STARTED
    @ /WebStart.jnlp
    -(CONNECTING)
    +(CONNECTED)
    Status: CONNECTED DOWNLOAD STARTED
    isCurrent: http://localhost/WebStart.jnlp = false
    Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
    Selecting proxy for: http://localhost/WebStart.jnlp
    best url for location=http://localhost/WebStart.jnlp state=CONNECTING DOWNLOAD STARTED is http://localhost/WebStart.jnlp by HEAD
    Key : Server ,Value : [Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)]
    Key : Accept-Ranges ,Value : [bytes]
    Key : Connection ,Value : [Keep-Alive]
    Key : Content-Type ,Value : [application/x-java-jnlp-file]
    Key : Keep-Alive ,Value : [timeout=5, max=100]
    Key : Last-Modified ,Value : [Wed, 02 Sep 2015 13:07:41 GMT]
    Key : Content-Length ,Value : [442]
    Key : Date ,Value : [Wed, 02 Sep 2015 13:13:30 GMT]
    Key : ETag ,Value : ["1ba-51ec35a097c7f"]
    Key : null ,Value : [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
    Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
    Selecting proxy for: socket://localhost:80
    Selected proxies: [DIRECT]
    Selecting proxy for: http://localhost/WebStart.jnlp
    All possible urls for location=http://localhost/WebStart.jnlp state=CONNECTING DOWNLOAD STARTED : [http://localhost/WebStart.jnlp, http://localhost/WebStart.jnlp]
    Detected online set to: true
    @ /WebStart.jnlp
    -(CONNECT)
    +(CONNECTING)
    Status: CONNECTING DOWNLOAD STARTED
    @ /WebStart.jnlp
    +(DOWNLOAD)
    Status: CONNECT DOWNLOAD STARTED
    @ /WebStart.jnlp
    +(CONNECT STARTED)
    Status: CONNECT STARTED
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java/net/URLPermission     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.SecurityDesc.<clinit>(SecurityDesc.java:164)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.JNLPFile.<init>(JNLPFile.java:137)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.PluginBridge.<init>(PluginBridge.java:90)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.PluginBridge.<init>(PluginBridge.java:67)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.NetxPanel.ourRunLoader(NetxPanel.java:101)     at sun.applet.AppletViewerPanelAccess.run(AppletViewerPanelAccess.java:86)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
    Exception while reflectively finding URLPermission - host is probably not running Java 8+
    JNLPRuntime already initialized
    Using NetX panel
    Read 181 entries from Firefox's preferences
    Found preferences file: /home/dan/.mozilla/firefox/vq92ezur.default/prefs.js
    Using firefox's profiles file: /home/dan/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini
    Starting security dialog thread
    Started processing of plugin-debug-to-console /run/user/1000/icedteaplugin-dan-XkKfMv/12261-icedteanp-plugin-debug-to-appletviewer
    Starting processing of plugin-debug-to-console /run/user/1000/icedteaplugin-dan-XkKfMv/12261-icedteanp-plugin-debug-to-appletviewer
    WARNING: key deployment.system.cachedir has no value, setting to default value
    No User level deployment.properties found.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/dan/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties (No such file or directory)     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DeploymentConfiguration.parsePropertiesFile(DeploymentConfiguration.java:655)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DeploymentConfiguration.findSystemConfigFile(DeploymentConfiguration.java:479)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DeploymentConfiguration.load(DeploymentConfiguration.java:292)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DeploymentConfiguration.load(DeploymentConfiguration.java:262)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPRuntime$DeploymentConfigurationHolder.initConfiguration(JNLPRuntime.java:451)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPRuntime$DeploymentConfigurationHolder.<clinit>(JNLPRuntime.java:446)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPRuntime.getConfiguration(JNLPRuntime.java:481)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DirectoryValidator.<init>(DirectoryValidator.java:224)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DeploymentConfiguration.move14AndOlderFilesTo15Structure(DeploymentConfiguration.java:829)     at net.sourceforge.jnlp.config.DeploymentConfiguration.move14AndOlderFilesTo15StructureCatched(DeploymentConfiguration.java:733)     at sun.applet.PluginMain.main(PluginMain.java:139) 
    cache: /home/dan/.cache/icedtea-web file exists:true
    config: /home/dan/.config/icedtea-web file exists: true
    System is already following XDG .cache and .config specifications
    2: /run/user/1000/icedteaplugin-dan-XkKfMv/12261-icedteanp-plugin-debug-to-appletviewer
    1: /run/user/1000/icedteaplugin-dan-XkKfMv/12261-icedteanp-appletviewer-to-plugin
    0: /run/user/1000/icedteaplugin-dan-XkKfMv/12261-icedteanp-plugin-to-appletviewer
    startup arguments:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception says

```
Multithreading : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

52 is the major class version in Java 8, and since you've complied the class `Multithreading` with Java 8, that version number makes sense.

You can verify this using:

```
javap -verbose Multithreading | grep "major"
```

`UnsupportedClassVersionError` usually happens when you are trying to load a class with lower Java version but the class is complied with a higher Java version.

In your case that shouldn't normally happen since you are using the same environment. But due to some reason (possibly something to do with the `net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader`) your JRE doesn't seem to like the 52 version.

---

You could try the following:

1. Compile your class using lower target version:

   `javac -target 1.6 Multithreading.java`
2. If that doesn't work, try switching to Oracle JDK instead of OpenJDK, compile again and see if it works.

Comment: Ok I switched to OracleJDK 9 and it works fine now, thx a lot

Answer (score -1):

It is run with the wrong java jre. (it is compiled with a higher java version than you have installed on the place where it runs)

Comment: I compiled and run it on the same machine; as shown above the jre and jdk are 1.8.0_45, so how can it be compiled in a lower version or how do I find out if it was?